# Adding attribute to TinyMCE node with attr not working

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that adds a button to TinyMCE, which lets you add an id attribute to the selected element. I have the button displaying, and when it is clicked it runs my function, which I'll call "idFunc" for this demo and it looks like this:

```
function idFunc() {

  // Make sure editor has focus.
  editor.focus();

  // Get currently selected node
  var selectednode = editor.selection.getNode();

  // Set the id attribute on the node
  selectednode.attr("id","newid");

}
```

With idFunc() written as above, nothing happens when I click my button. If I change the last line to an alert like this:

```
function idFunc() {

  editor.focus();

  var selectednode = editor.selection.getNode();

  // Alert with the selected node
  alert(selectednode);

}
```

I get an alert as expected, which says:

> **The page at mytestingdomain.com says:** [object HTMLParagraphElement]

If I have my caret in a div instead of a p element, it says:

> **The page at mytestingdomain.com says:** [object HTMLDivElement]

So I know I'm close, but the `attr()` function isn't adding any attributes to any elements in the TinyMCE editor.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is easy.
`editor.selection.getNode()` gives you the common ancestor node (not a jQuery object).

To set the id attribute on the node you may call one of the following commands:

```
selectednode.setAttribute("id","newid");
```

or

```
selectednode.id = "newid";
```

or using jQuery

```
$(selectednode).attr("id","newid");
```

Comment: Geez, that **was** easy! I don't know how I never tried any of these combinations. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JoeRhoney: glad to have been able to help :)